# .net ServiceModel CustomBinding settings?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume a Java web-service using .NET C#.

What kinda of custombinding must I use in order to get it to generate a soap request that looks like this:

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <ds:Signature Id="SIG-6" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-5">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue> …</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>…</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-721822786FFDB4997C138057342695219">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-721822786FFDB4997C138057342695220">
                  <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">  … </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>

 <soap:Body ID=” id-5” >

 <!--  Web service call ->
   
 </soap-env:Body>
/soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is what I have so far, but it is not correct:

```
    <bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="ServicesBindingSOAP">
      <security authenticationMode="" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="false"/>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Could it be that it is not possible to config the customBinding to do what I need and that I will have to pretty much write my own?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it?